# NSUserDefaults errors on Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

For some reasons, I can't seem to get my NSUserDefaults to work correctly under Swift 2.0.  It work fine under the older version, but under Swift 2.0, it doesn't work.  I know the coding has been changed for Swift 2.0, but for some reason, all the information filled in the tableview goes away once I leave that page.  Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnSave() {

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            if name.text == "" {


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey:"name")

                userDefaults.synchronize()

        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            defaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "name")

            super.viewDidLoad()

               }
        }
```

Comment: You set a space for key ``name`` by ``defaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "name")``. But in the condition ``if name.text == ""``, there is no space in it.

Comment: Ok..let me check to see if that will work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I changed it.

Comment: Maybe you would like to update the question and add more codes or provide a full repository. It helps to figure out the issue which is probably not related to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Ok. Let me look into it.

Comment: First of all, remove one of the unnecessary  `let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` statements and be consistent. Use either NSUSerDefaults.standardUserDefaults.something ... or userDefaults variable. There is no point of creating userDefaults variable if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this

```
import UIKit

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

  @IBAction func btnSave() {


    if name.text == "" {

      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

      userDefaults.setObject(name.text, forKey:"name")

      userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    name.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("name")

  }
}
```

Comment: Ramsy, sorry for the late reply but i think this one work better than the last.  Cleaner and easier.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` you're erasing the info in *name*, so everytime you enter your view, it will get deleted.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "name")
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Also, since `name` is a UITextField and not a String, when you're saving your name, it should be done like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name.text, forKey:"name")
```

instead of this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey:"name")
```

Also, inside your `btnSave()` method, you're only saving the name.text if it's equal to "". So if you enter any other information, it won't be saved. I'd recommend modifying it so it looks something like this (you could use `guard` instead of `if name.text` also):

```
@IBAction func btnSave() {
    if name.text == "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(name.text, forKey:"name")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

P.S: Remember that `NSUserDefaults` is intended for user preferences. I'd recommend against saving large amounts of data into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Do i need to change the let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() and  userDefaults.synchronize()?

Comment: I added more info to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I didn't modify my coding based on your recommendation above, but the data still isn't holding up and once I pressed the save button, the app crashes.

Comment: I don't see any reason of this crashing unless the outlet for the UITextField `name` is not linked to the actual UITextField in Interface Builder.

Comment: The name is attached to the UItextfield.  I'm not too concern about the crash at the moment.  i can't seem to get the data to retain still.  BTW, there only a few data to store on the NSUserDefaults.